# Angular - Set Default Value For nbgDropDown

Tags: angular

I have this form where users can enter their cat information (name and color) and then save it to Firebase database.
How can I make the color "Orange" as the default value on the new Cat but still retain the cat color on edit?

**What I want**

New Cat Form:

> Cat Name:  Placeholder
>
> Cat Color: Orange   <-- This

Edit Cat Form:

> Cat Name:  UserEnteredName
>
> Cat Color: UserChoseColor

**What I have**

New Cat Form:

> Cat Name:  Placeholder
>
> Cat Color: (empty)  <-- THIS

Edit Cat Form:

> Cat Name:  UserEnteredName
>
> Cat Color: UserChoseColor

HTML:

```
<div ngbDropdown placement="top" class="d-inline-block">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>{{cat.color}}</button>
  <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
    <button *ngFor="let color of getColors()" ngbDropdownItem (click)="setColor(color)">{{color}}</button> <!-- THIS -->
  </div>
</div>
<button (click)="onSubmit()">Save Kitty</button>
```

TS:

```
public cat: MyCat = new MyCat({});

public setCat(cat: MyCat) {
  this.cat = cat;
  this.form.setValue({
    catName: this.cat.name,
  });
}

get nameForm(): FormControl {
  return this.form.controls.catName as FormControl;
}

getColors(): Array<string> {
  return [
    'White',
    'Black',
    'Orange'
  ];
}

setColor(color: string) {
  this.cat.color = color;
}

onSubmit() {
  if (this.form.valid) {
    const kitty = new MyCat({});
    kitty.name = this.nameForm.value;
    kitty.color = this.cat.color;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use ngbDropdown as a form field. That's not what it's for. It's for navigation links or buttons in a dropdown. What you want is a good old select box.

Comment: you simple write this.cat.color='Orange'. But your'e mixing differents concept. first you need decided if you want use ReactiveForms or not. e.g., your'e using a formControl for catName, and change the variable cat.color using a ngbDropdown. Your button submit, return a new Cat() bsed in this values. Why not use a FormGroup with name and color or [(NgModel)] to realation view (the .html) and model (the variables in .ts). Your code works, but it's not a natural way to do the things, take a look to official docs: https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the information.  I will go back to the select option box.